# How to use a Web proxy?

Tags: http-proxy, ad-hoc-network

I've a PC with a LAN connection that is connected to the internet. My system is added to a Domain. Now I've created an ad-hoc wifi connection and my mobile devices can access the HTTP server in my system.I do that using the IP address of the ad-hoc connection.
Now I want these mobile devices to access Internet through my PC. Can I use any proxy servers to do this? I cannot share the internet connection since I'm in a Domain.
Can you please let me know if a proxy server will be able to help the mobile devices to access the Internet in my PC?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure an instance of the [Squid proxy service](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/BinaryPackages#Windows). [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is usually used for Linux machines, but their site does have some windows binaries you can use, so that should work fine. Squid's just the one I've used the most.

[Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) is another you could check out.

Google searching around should reveal various additional options.

Still, it sounds like you should be able to configure your main machine to share it's Internet connection, but whatever - proxy servers can be something of a solution too.

Comment: Thanks. I could not download the above application (since it is blocked here). I downloaded Charles Proxy and was able to setup the proxy

Comment: Squid or Privoxy are blocked for you? Wow, police state. Sorry to hear that friend. Anyway, glad you were able to find some fit.